# Local Plugin to customise in messaging page

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I'm new to moodle plugin development and wanted to know if its possible to let my local plugin access the messages page and edit in the specified area the arrow is pointing at , e.g i want to add the date of the latest message there .

Any help would be appreciated

[Show Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEfdZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display additional informations in the  messages page, good to customize the corresponding page. Using local plugins you can set the values in database, but to display the values , you need to customize it.

Comment: How can i customize the messages page without changing in the core code ? 
Is copying the whole messaging system of moodle into a local plugin would work ?